# Component to component communication in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I am rebuilding the Gmail UI for a small project in Ember. I have made the left side bar, the actions at the top(delete, mark as read) and the message list three different components with no parent to child relationship.

I am trying to get the select all action working. I have researched a lot but I don't know how to send the action of selecting a checkbox at the top, to selecting all checkboxes in the message list. Also would I set a property on the component called isChecked? How would the top actions component know about the properties and actions of the message list component without a parent child relationship?

If you need more clarification please ask.

Comment: Your component may have some property, binded to controller's property. And the same controller's property may be binded to a property of other component. Component A <---> Controller <---> Component B

Comment: That makes sense. But shouldn't i avoid the use of controllers for 2.0?

Comment: I don't know, didn't even read about 2.0 yet. Do you have plans to re-write your app when 2.0 will be released? If no, then don't think about 2.0.

Comment: You bind route properties to communication between datas